# Bubblesort not Sorting

Tags: c, sorting

I implemented Bubblesort but the only problem left is that it simply isn't Sorting the Array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 50
int m = SIZE;
void Sorting(int *x ,int m)
{
  int n = m;
  do{
    int nn = 1;
    for(int i=0; i <n-1; i++){
      if(x[i] > x[i+1]){
        int x1 = x[i+1];
        x[i+1] = x[i];
        x[i] = x1;
        nn = i + 1;
      }
    }
    n = nn;
  }while(n > 1);
}
```

I will also give you my test main function if my little error is hidden there.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  int x[SIZE];
  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    x[i] = rand() % 100;
  }
  void Sorting(int *x,int m);
  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    printf("%d" , x[i]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to actually call the function `Sorting` from main. Change `void Sorting(int *x,int m)` to `Sorting(x, m);`

Comment: Not only is your program not sorting, but it does not even compile. You could have stated it in you question ;) Calling `Sorting(x, SIZE)` does the trick.

Comment: In the future for everyone's sake I'd recommend using variable names that help identify a variable's purpose rather than a bunch of ambiguous letters (e.g. instead of a, b, c, d try something like smallest, largest, count, array).

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but to help people read your code, you should use descriptive variable names instead of x, m, n, nn, etc. It makes it hard to interpret. I would also avoid using global variables (`int m = SIZE;` is a global variable).

Comment: I'm using it with gcc and im compiling itt with no errors its just printing out the unsorted array

Comment: But thanks to all the answers I was just stuck in my mind i think and did search for the error in the Sorting function and not in the main function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling the Sorting function in main, you're declaring it.

Comment: Thank you I was frustrate with not finding my error that i didnt see this mistake